# Angular2, on initial loading styles.*********.bundle.css file taking more time to load

Tags: angular, loading

I'm working on an Angular2 project, on initial loading styles.*********.bundle.css file taking more time to load[image]

Can anyone help me how to avoid it?

Comment: The status of 304 Not Modified suggests that's coming from the browser's cache, not from the server, so it's unclear why it takes so long. How is this being deployed?

Comment: Its deployed in AWS ElasticBenstalk tomcat - environment, angular2 app